# Reactjs: which special character in string variable would result in new line when the variable is in html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I try to pass a variable to html tag and want to display a list of strings:

```
...

incompleteFields = ["Name", "Gender", "Age"].join(`\n`)
this.setState({incompleteFields: incompleteFields})
...

          <div className={classes.modalPaper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Warning</h2>
            <br/>
            <p 
             id="transition-modal-description"
            >
              some fields are empty: &#10;
              { this.state.incompleteFields }
            </p>
            
          </div>
```

However, the following is displayed:

```
Warning

some fields are empty:Name Gender Age
```

I want to display:

```
Warning

some fields are empty:
Name 
Gender 
Age
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to insert a '/n' for new line, instead map the array and display items in each line

Comment: What would you use to create a line break in pure HTML ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map function:

```
...

incompleteFields = ["Name", "Gender", "Age"]
this.setState({incompleteFields: incompleteFields})
...

          <div className={classes.modalPaper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Warning</h2>
            <br/>
            <p 
             id="transition-modal-description"
            >
              some fields are empty: &#10;
              { this.state.incompleteFields && this.state.incompleteFields.map((field) => (<br/>{field})) }
            </p>
            
          </div>
```

Comment: `TypeError: this.state.incompleteFields.map is not a function`

Comment: by the way, I did `{ this.state.incompleteFields.map((field) => (<br>{field}</br>)) }` instead. Otherwise the IDE complains that the code is not valid

Comment: You can also do `<><br/>{field}</>`

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: The correct way should be putting `{ this.state.incompleteFields && this.state.incompleteFields.map((field) => (<p>{field}</p>)) }` after the `</p>` line

Comment: You can use any approach to achieve this :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this and the items will be listed one after another as you expect.

```js
incompleteFields = ["Name", "Gender", "Age"];
this.setState({incompleteFields: incompleteFields})
```

```css
.inc {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className={classes.modalPaper}>
  <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Warning</h2>
  <br/>
  <p 
   id="transition-modal-description"
  >
    some fields are empty;
    { this.state.incompleteFields.map(incomplete => {
      return(<span className='inc'>{incomplete}</span>)
    }) }
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid creating a new .css file and putting the `.inc {
  display: block;
}` code in that file?

Comment: Yeah, you can make it as div instead of span. Otherwise you can use </ br> tag

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with your code. just adding css property :

```
white-space:pre;
```

Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag or `\p`.

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ["Name", "Gender", "Age"].join(`\n`);
```

```css
#test{
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Where exactly do I put `#test{
  white-space:pre;
}` ?

Comment: id="transition-modal-description" . adding to this id